# Como passar um parâmetro de uma annotation para outra?

Tags: java, annotation

Como consigo substituir o valor do `@ConditionalOnExpression` pelo valor passado na annotation `SecurityConfig`?

Código atual:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${auth.provedor:NULL}'.equals('DEV-JWT')")
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
          prePostEnabled = true, 
          securedEnabled = true, 
          jsr250Enabled = true)
public @interface SecurityConfig {
    String value();
}
```

Exemplo de código desejado (porém não funciona):

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnExpression(SecurityConfig.class.getValue())
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
          prePostEnabled = true, 
          securedEnabled = true, 
          jsr250Enabled = true)
public @interface SecurityConfig {
    String value();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse caso meu erro foi muito simples, eu não deveria tentar pegar os valores nas annotations afinal são interfaces e sim na implementação.